# Get files from same folder as script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javascript and jQuery, I'm trying to load a file dynamically from the same folder as the script is currently being loaded from using the following code:

```
var script = document.currentScript || (function () {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
})();
browser = window.browser || {};
browser.extension = {};
browser.extension.getURL = function (s) {
    return script.src.replace(/[^/]+$/, "") + s;
};

loadCSS = function () {
    // Dynamically load  CSS.
    var css = document.createElement("link");
    css.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    css.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    css.setAttribute("href", browser.extension.getURL("cssFile.css"));
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css);
}
```

It works fine for Chrome, FF and Safari, but the URL path screws up only for IE.

Are thereget alternative load methods I could use which load a css file from the same folder as the script itself?

Comment: Check that your custom "currentScript" function returns the same as "document.currentScript" does, as "document.currentScript" is not supported on IE

Comment: Surely you can provide some details of the differences and what path IE tries to use.

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry forgot to mention that -
IE uses the main asset folder that other scripts load from

Comment: that doesn't tell us much since no paths are shown anywhere in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code
for javascript files

```
    function addJavascript(fileName, onload) {
        var imported = document.createElement('script');
        document.head.appendChild(imported);            
        imported.src = fileName;
        if(onload != undefined)
            imported.onload = onload;
    }
    function removeJavascript(fileName) {
        $('head script[src*="' + fileName + '"]').remove();
    }
```

and for css files

```
    function addCss(fileName) {
        var link = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + fileName + '">';
        $('head').append(link);            
    }
    function removeCss(fileName) {
        $('link[rel=stylesheet][href*="' + fileName + '"]').remove();
    }
```